# Are empty lines generally considered output?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If you have a program that is like this for example:

```
 print("Hi there \n")
 print("Hello")
```

Would this program be considered to have 2 or 3 lines of output?I know blank lines aren't really anything, but it's still something that the program does.

Comment: Why do you need to know? It depends on whom you ask, this isn't something set in stone anywhere.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I need to know because it's a question from an assignment I have for my python class haha. I have Python Programming: An introduction to Computer Science by John Zelle, 2nd edition

Comment: I'd say that for that question the answer would be 3; they want to see if you know what the `\n` does, in conjunction with the `print()` function. This isn't about line count *in general*. There is no such concept, really.

Comment: Questions of definition are just that: definitions aren't facts, so there's no "answer". Pick a definition that suits your purpose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you ran the program your output would look like this:

```
hi there 

hello
```

if you then put that output into a file and ran `wc -l file.txt` it would return with `3 file.txt` meaning that were are three lines in the file.

Answer (score -5):

I would say two lines.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

f=open('file.txt', 'w')
f.write("Hi there \n")
f.write("Hello")
f.close()


count=0
with open ('file.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        count+=1

print count
```

Result

```
2
```

Comment: `print()` adds newlines, whereas `f.write()` does not.

Comment: In terminal. If you run the script from something else, it outputs zero lines. But in terminal you can get an empty line just by printing nothing.

Comment: `print()` writes to `sys.stdout`, and adds a newline unless you tell it not to (by setting the `end` keyword argument to something else). If you are redirecting `sys.stdout` then you wouldn't see that output, but it still produces that output to go *somewhere*.

Comment: AFAIK, "/n" is just a character. It doesn't produce any line. That's how terminal renders it. "In computing, a newline, also known as a line ending, end of line (EOL), or line break, is a special character signifying the end of a line of text."  - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Comment: So why does your answer produce just 1 newline and then count lines, then claim that that produces the same thing as using `print()`? I'm not sure what you are arguing about now.

Comment: But how did you manage "if you then put that output into a file" by copy-paste from sys.stdout? You are a bit of a troll eh?

Comment: Uhm, no, I think you may have misunderstood something. I'm explaining how `print()` *works*. Redirecting is the act of instructing the shell or console to take the output of a program and write it somewhere else. You may want to watch out with calling people 'trolls' when they give you feedback.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80230/discussion-between-alex-ivanov-and-martijn-pieters).